# Combining IF else with LEFT to hide columns

Tags: excel, show-hide, if-statement, vba

I'm trying to write some code to Hide columns if the first 3 characters of cells in a range equal the contents of another. I have the code for hiding columns if cells in a range are blank as this;-

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range, cell As Range
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set r = Me.Range("C8:R8")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each cell In r
    If cell.Value = "" Then
    cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
    cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    End If

    Next

ErrHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

And the code for identifiying the first 3 charcters of a cell;-

```
Dim LResult As String

LResult = Left ("Alphabet",3)
```

But how do I combine the two, referencing a specific cell rather than "Alphabet"?

Cant get this to work - any suggestions?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range, cell As Range

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set r = Me.Range("B7:CG7")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Row = 1
col = 1

For Each cell In r
  If cell.Value = "" And Left(cell.Value, 3) = cell(Row, col).Value Then
    cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Else
    cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End If


Next
ErrHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have almost the working code. You are comparing cell.Value to an empty string - now just apply Left to it

```
LResult = Left (cell.Value,3)
```

Edit:

```
row = 20
col = 30

For Each cell In r
  If cell.Value = "" and  Left (cell.Value,3) = Cell(row, col).Value Then
    cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Else
    cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End If
```

where you want data from cell at row and col (I used 20, 30 as the example)

Comment: Mark - sorryi'm a nebie at VBA - where would I place your code into the part for hiding columns?

Comment: Also where do i reference the cell that the result of the left statement compares to?

Comment: Thnaks - how do i define cell2?

Comment: I chnaged to use Cell(row,col) for more complete - but you can use anything that identifies a cell

Comment: Dan, Mark was good enough to answer your question.  Why not accept his answer and then ask another question?